smart contract deployment taking too much eth as gas fee
I'm following JSMastery's web3.0 project on YT and this is my solidity code

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCounter;
    event Transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount,
        string message,
        uint256 timestamp,
        string keyword
    );
    struct TransferStruct {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint256 amount;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string keyword;
    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(
        address payable receiver,
        uint256 amount,
        string memory message,
        string memory keyword
    ) public {
        transactionCounter += 1;
        transactions.push(
            TransferStruct(
                msg.sender,
                receiver,
                amount,
                message,
                block.timestamp,
                keyword
            )
        );
        emit Transfer(
            msg.sender,
            receiver,
            amount,
            message,
            block.timestamp,
            keyword
        );
    }

    function getAllTransactions()
        public
        view
        returns (TransferStruct[] memory)
    {
        return transactions;
    }

    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        //return transactions count
        return transactionCounter;
    }
}

I'm using hardhat for deployment.
When I deployed this, I found that it almost cost 0.35 sepolia testnet eth, which I think is way high, when Adrian (whose video I'm following) took like 0.0028 ropsten eth, even if it was two years ago. I want to know the reason why this happened, if I'm doing anything wrong, because I'm already short on testnet eth as it is.
YOUTUBE VIDEO LINK: https://youtu.be/Wn_Kb3MR_cU?si=yvo0441XuK81dSAj

Gas cost is not a constant value.
So, there are a few things to keep in mind.
Gas usage - This indicates the units of gas any transaction will use. This is not Ether, or wei, or money, this is just a numerical value, that we get after adding up all the opcodes' gas usage.
Gas price - This indicates the price of one gas unit. And this is denoted in Gwei, a lower denomination of Ether. 1 ETH = 1000000000 Gwei.
Now comes the Gas cost - This is the total gas units used in a transaction multiplied by the gas price.
So for example your contract uses 100 units of gas while deploying, and the gas price is 20 gwei, then total gas cost will be 100 x 20 = 2000. Means this transaction will use 2000 gwei, or 0.000002 ETH.
The video you are watching dates back to 2021 when the gas prices were different. maybe 10 gwei per gas unit, so the cost would be half. (The values used are just examples)
And the gas price depends on the network congestion, which means if more people are trying to send transactions at the same time, the price increases, and vice versa.
Hope that's clear

yep it's clear, thanks

Awesome, mark it as answer if the query is solved.
